# Spark Mesos Cluster Mode using Dispatcher

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I have only a single machine and want to run spark jobs with mesos cluster mode. It might make more sense to run with a cluster of nodes, but I mainly want to test out mesos first to check if it's able to utilize resources more efficiently (run multiple spark jobs at the same time without static partitioning). I have tried a number of ways but without success. Here is what I did:

1. Build mesos and run both mesos master and slaves (2 slaves in same machines).

   ```
   sudo ./bin/mesos-master.sh --ip=127.0.0.1 --work_dir=/var/lib/mesos
   sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --port=5051 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos1
   sudo ./bin/mesos-slave.sh --master=127.0.0.1:5050 --port=5052 --work_dir=/tmp/mesos2
   ```
2. Run the spark-mesos-dispatcher

   ```
   sudo ./sbin/start-mesos-dispatcher.sh --master mesos://localhost:5050
   ```
3. The submit the app with dispatcher as master url.

   ```
   spark-submit  --master mesos://localhost:7077 <other-config> <jar file>
   ```

But it doesnt work:

```
    E0925 17:30:30.158846 807608320 socket.hpp:174] Shutdown failed on fd=61: Socket is not connected [57]
    E0925 17:30:30.159545 807608320 socket.hpp:174] Shutdown failed on fd=62: Socket is not connected [57]
```

If I use spark-submit  --deploy-mode cluster, then I got another error message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.deploy.rest.SubmitRestConnectionException: Unable to connect to server
```

It work perfectly if I don't use dispatcher but using mesos master url directly:  --master mesos://localhost:5050 (client mode). According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) , cluster mode is not supported for Mesos clusters, but they give another instruction for cluster mode [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode). So it's kind of confusing? My question is:

1. How I can get it works?
2. Should I use client mode instead of cluster mode if I submit the app/jar directly from the master node?
3. If I have a single computer, should I spawn 1 or more mesos slave processes. Basically, I have a number of spark job and dont want to do static partitioning of resources. But when using mesos without static partitioning, it seems to be much slower?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I use your scenario to try, it could be work.
One thing different , I use ip address to instead of "localhost" and "127.0.0.1"
So just try again and to check http://your_dispatcher:8081 (on browser) if exist.

This is my spark-submit command:

```
$spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master mesos://192.168.11.79:7077 --class "SimpleApp"  SimpleAppV2.jar
```

If success, you can see as below

```
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.5.0",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20151006164749-0001",
  "success" : true
}
```

When I got your error log as yours, I reboot the machine and retry your step. It also work.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be two things you're confusing: launching a Spark application in a cluster (as opposed to locally) and launching the driver into the cluster.

From the top of [Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html):

> The spark-submit script in Spark’s bin directory is used to launch applications on a cluster. It can use all of Spark’s supported cluster managers through a uniform interface so you don’t have to configure your application specially for each one.

So, Mesos is one of the supported cluster managers and hence you can [run Spark apps on a Mesos cluster](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-mesos.html#cluster-mode).

What Mesos as time of writing does not support is launching the driver into the cluster, this is what the command line argument `--deploy-mode` of `./bin/spark-submit`specifies. Since the default value of `--deploy-mode` is `client` you can just omit it, or if you want to explicitly specify it, then use:

```
./bin/spark-submit --deploy-mode client ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 6066 port instead of 7077.   The newer versions of Spark prefer the REST api for submitting jobs.

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5388